# Remove complete object graph in JPA

Tags: database, hibernate, object, jpa, graph

Lets assume that there is a complex entity with many-to-one and one-to-many child entities which in turn also have these kind of relations and bi-directional associations and there are foreign key constraints involved on some level. 
How is it possible to remove (i.e delete) the complete object graph without cascade?

Answer (score 1):

Without cascading deletes, you have to remove the graph manually, node by node, beginning with entities having no dependencies and working your way back. In graph theory terms, this is a toposort. You could automate deletion of arbitrary graphs by reflecting against the structure Hibernate produces, or at a lower level, querying system tables for foreign key information, but there's little reason to do that if cascading deletes are possible.